# Deploying in necessitas?

Tags: android, qt, apk, aidl, qt-necessitas

I have the following problem: when I try to deploy from necessitas on an actual device, I can't get through the .apk creation phase. Ant stops with error after finding .aidl files.

Here is the output that I get from ant(I added an echo to see aidl call arguments, so it might look unusual):

```
echo: started Sat Mar 09 08:54:26 CET 2013
     [echo] Handling aidl files...

echo: finished Sat Mar 09 08:54:26 CET 2013 (0ms)

echo: started Sat Mar 09 08:54:26 CET 2013
     [echo] executable="D:\necessitas\android-sdk\platform-tools\aidl.exe"
     [echo] framework="D:\necessitas\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\framework.aidl"
     [echo] libraryBinAidlFolderPathRefid="project.library.bin.aidl.folder.path"
     [echo] genFolder="D:\workspace\Test\android\gen"
     [echo] aidlOutFolder="D:\workspace\Test\android\bin\aidl"
     [echo] path="D:\workspace\Test\android\src"

echo: finished Sat Mar 09 08:54:26 CET 2013 (0ms)

aidl: started Sat Mar 09 08:54:26 CET 2013
     [aidl] Found 2 AIDL files.
     [aidl] Compiling 2 AIDL files.
Packaging Error: Command 'D:\necessitas/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin/ant.bat clean debug' failed.Exit code: 1
Error while building/deploying project Test (target: Necessitas Qt 4.8.2 for Android armv7a)
When executing step 'Packaging for Android'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. The ant ".jar"s  which contain build tasks for android are built for jre 1.7 while I was using 1.8. Just had to install the 1.7 version and change the PATH variable.